2D Top Down Slime Jump
I am trying to make a Top down game with the main character as a slime. i am trying to get it so when the player clicks with the mouse the slime jumps to that location and actually looks like a jump.
if you want me to add more information please let me know
I have tried using a Vector2.MoveTowards for mainly the x and a bit the y and then using a Sine Wave to try and get a jump motion but i can't get it right.
Vector2 moveTo = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, 5 * Time.deltaTime);

        transform.position = new Vector2(moveTo.x, /*moveTo.y +*/ Mathf.Sin((transform.position.x - startXPos) / (targetPos.x - startXPos)));


Could you add more context? This is one of the use cases that might be easier to handle in a Coroutine

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Id imagine this has more to do with scaling the object since its 2d.  Make a routine that scales the slime up until the apex of the jump, and then back down until "grounded" again.  Probably want some easing in the movement as well, to simulate the 3rd dimension.
